# Uncaught TypeError: this.rotate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, uncaught-exception, jquery-rotate, nodejs-8.11

I have created a function for rotating a div element. This works fine as a standalone code in HTML and when I tried to incorporate in my project the rotate function throws an error as "Uncaught TypeError: this.rotate is not a function". My project is based on node version 8 and I have converted HTML to Pug and used it. I have given my code below:

```
      var rotation = 0;
      $.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
      $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
      '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
      '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
      'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
      };
      $('.box').click(function() {
      rotation += 5;
      this.rotate(rotation);
      });
```

Comment: Shouldn’t that be `$(this).rotate(rotation);`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use arrow functions or bind the function to 'this'

```
  var rotation = 0;
  $.fn.rotate =(degrees) => {
  $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
  '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
  '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
  'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
  };
  $('.box').click(() => {
  rotation += 5;
  this.rotate(rotation);
  });
```

> The handling of this is also different in arrow functions compared to
> regular functions.
>
> In short, with arrow functions there are no binding of this.
>
> In regular functions the this keyword represented the object that
> called the function, which could be the window, the document, a button
> or whatever.
>
> With arrow functions the this keyword always represents the object
> that defined the arrow function.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp

Good luck!